# How to link to :id pages rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been trying to find out a better way to link to pages that contains /:id's in them. Because the way I'm doing it now works but can easily break if I change something.

Currently I have two of these examples. One to link to your profile done like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Your profile", root_url + "users/#{current_user.id}"  %></li>
```

and the other:

```
<%= link_to "Apply now", root_url + "answers/#{f.id}" %>
```

how do I make it so that I don't have to rely on the manual change of this. On my rake routes I cant write 'answers_path/#{f.id}' for example as it doesn't show me any path.

So how do I do this? My routes setup for these two are currently:

```
match '/answers/:id',     to: 'answers#show',                         via: 'get'
match '/users/:id',       to: 'users#show',                           via: 'get'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following should do it for you.

```
<li><%= link_to "Your profile", user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Apply now", answer_path(f.id) %>
```

I do, however, recommend you review the following Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Last one worked however on the user_path I get this: 
undefined method `user_path' 

I think it might be because I have that link in my layouts/_header. How would I properly call it? Thanks for good tips so far

Comment: There's no need to specify the ID explicitly. `user_path(current_user)` would work. Equally, I believe `= link_to "Your profile", current_user` will also work providing `current_user` is an instance of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `match` I would define `resources` routes

```
resources :users, :answers
```

Now you can use:

```
<%= link_to 'Your Profile', current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Apply Now', f %>
```

You can learn more about rails path helpers and resource routing here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Also, if you don't need all the CRUD actions, you can use `only:`

```
resources :users, :answers, only: :show
```